# Error handling stopping after first loop through For Each loop

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have already solved this problem, though I don't understand why my solution was required.   I wanted to make a way to check properties on all forms and all controls within my database so I came up with the following code:

```
Public Function CheckPropertyAllForms()

    Dim obj As Object
    Dim ctl As Control

    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllForms

        DoCmd.OpenForm obj.Name, acDesign, , , , acHidden
        blnFound = False

        For Each ctl In Forms(obj.Name).Controls
        On Error GoTo Next_Control

            If Nz(ctl.ControlSource, "") <> "" Then
                If ctl.ControlSource = "Certain_Field" Then
                    blnFound = True
                End If
            End If

Next_Control:
        Next ctl

        If blnFound = True Then
            Debug.Print obj.Name
        End If

        DoCmd.Close acForm, obj.Name

    Next obj
End Function
```

However this code would only work once, the second time around it would display the error as if error handling was turned off.  So I updated it to this:

```
Public Function CheckPropertyAllForms()

    Dim obj As Object
    Dim ctl As Control

    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllForms

        DoCmd.OpenForm obj.Name, acDesign, , , , acHidden
        blnFound = False

        For Each ctl In Forms(obj.Name).Controls
        On Error GoTo Err_Handler

            If Nz(ctl.ControlSource, "") <> "" Then
                If ctl.ControlSource = "Certain_Field" Then
                    blnFound = True
                End If
            End If

Next_Control:
        Next ctl

        If blnFound = True Then
            Debug.Print obj.Name
        End If

        DoCmd.Close acForm, obj.Name

    Next obj

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Resume Next_Control
End Function
```

Which works exactly how I want it to, however I couldn't find an answer online as to WHY this was happening with my first set of code.  Could someone let me know what is happening with my first version of this function to cause the error handling to quit?

Edit: I should also point out that clearly the error handling will be needed because not all controls have a control source.  Additionally I don't have a control type check because this function gets updated when a different property is going to be checked.

Comment: You need to have an `On Error GoTo 0` statement, also.  Probably, right before your `Next_Control:` statement.

Comment: So if you want to inspect a different property, say `.Enabled`, you revise the code accordingly.  Then if you want to check `.ControlSource` again (maybe for a different string value) you change the code back again.  Argh!  I think you're better than that, Newd!  ;-)

Comment: @ HansUp Haha, ya I know that is super inefficient.  It is used so super rarely that I just haven't gotten around to sitting down and writing it in full.  In the future I plan to write two separate function, one for checking string property values and one for Booleans each one accepting parameters to let the function know what property it is checking.  Additionally I am going to need ones that do the same for the forms themselves too.

Answer (score 1):

Along with your `On Error` statement, you need to have an `On Error GoTo 0` statement, too. In your case, it would probably go right before your `Next_Control` and you could actually get rid of that so your loop would look like this:

```
    For Each ctl In Forms(obj.Name).Controls
    On Error Resume Next

        If Nz(ctl.ControlSource, "") <> "" Then
            If ctl.ControlSource = "Certain_Field" Then
                blnFound = True
            End If
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Next ctl
```

The reason for this is that in your first case, the error handler never *clears* the error object, and there can only be one error active at a time. When an error is active, and another error raises, the handler fails.

Comment: I think with `On Error GoTo Resume Next` you mean `On Error Resume Next`.  I had tried that originally, however this cause the blnFound to always toggle to true.  I can only assume that this is because since the if statement itself causes an error and the resume next causes it to enter the for loop.

Comment: I had also though that as you said the first error was still not "Handled" so just below `Next_Control` I added `Err.Clear` hoping it would reset it for the next time.  Though it didn't work either.

Comment: Yrs you caught the mistake it should be On Error Resume Next.  You will need to set your boolean to False on the subsequent line to avoid what you describe in your comment

Comment: Though the blnFound is for the form for loop.  So if it is reset to false within the ctl loop then it wouldn't perform what it needs to.  So lets say the first control is valid and toggles blnFound to true, then an error happens the end result would be blnFound being false even though it did find the control.

Comment: If it's true do you just want to exit the loop then?  It seems like this has adequately answered your original Q, now it is just a matter of correcting the logic elsewhere...